# Dynamic max/min matrix based on proportions in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following Excel table:

```
         A           B              C
1     Product     Discount      Proportion of Discount
2   Product A       85%            
3   Product B       85%            33%   --> 33% of the products have discount of 85%
4   Product C       75%            17%   --> 17% of the products have discount of 75%
5   Product D       70%            17%   --> 17% of the products have discount of 70%
6   Product E       50%            
7   Product F       50%            33%   --> 33% of the products have discount of 50%
8
```

In **Column A** you can find different products and in **Column B** their discounts and in **Column C** the proportion of the discounts in the list.

Now I want to have a formula that does the following:

The formula should go through **Column C** and **sum up** proportion by proportion - starting by the product with the highest discount according to Column B - until it reaches a **total proportion** of **at least 60%**. 
In the above example that would mean:

```
Product A&B (33%) + Product C (17%) + Product D (17%) = 67%
```

Once the formula has reached this minimum proportion of 60% it defines the Matrix to get the maximum or minimum value (discount) out of it.
In the above example that would mean:

```
MATRIX = B2:B5 (Product A&B, Product C, Product D)
```

This matrix in the end is used for the MAX or MIN formula:

```
=MAX/MIN(B2:B5)
```

Do you have any idea which formula I could use to solve this issue?

Something like:

```
= Once SUM(C2:C7) reaches at least 60% then use the matrix resulting from the values in the 60% sum (B2:B5)
```

Comment: Please write expected result for above example

Comment: To get the matrix which should be used for the max/min formula. In the example above that would be B2:B5 because it contains only the highest values (discounts) which have a combined proportion of at least 60%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more column (starting from D2) with formula:

```
=IF(AND(D1<0.6,D1>=0),SUM(C$2:C2),-1)
```

Then for calculation use that column as criteria

```
=MAXIFS(B2:B10,D2:D10,">0")/MINIFS(B2:B10,D2:D10,">0")
```

If you can't use MAXIFS/MINIFS formula (for earlier versions of Excel) then in D2 enter:

```
=IF(D1<0.6, SUM(C$2:C2), "")
```

And result is this (confirmed with ctr+shift+enter, not just enter):

```
=MAX(IF(D2:D10<>"", B2:B10))/MIN(IF(D2:D10<>"", B2:B10))
```

A curly brackets {} must appear around your formula (You can't enter them manually).

Comment: It works good. Do you also know if there is a way to do this without the additional Column D?

Comment: I've tried that first and failed :) If I find a solution I will post it.